# How to create generic array of class with two type parameter and constrain?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm trying to create generic array in java but it results in error. Can any one help me on this?

Please find my code below:

```
public class GenericArrayTest<TKey extends Comparable,TValue>
                                   implements Iterable<Map.Entry<TKey,TValue>> {
  private TKey[] _arrayCOll;

  public void test(){
    _arrayCOll = new TKey[10];//error "Cannot create a generic array of TKey"
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<Entry<TKey, TValue>> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
  }

}
```

Note: I could not know the class type so that i could not use the below solution
[How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Thanks in advance.
Sarath

Comment: Try:  E _arrayColl  = new TKey[10];    or      T _arrayColl = new TKey[10];

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java